# Add binding to elements that are created in codebehind

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ViewModel from which I want to update my View. The ViewModel has properties that utilize a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` to dynamically update the elements on my view.

For most of my elements in my view, I use a BindingContext, i.e.

```
BindingContext = carouselViewModel;
```

However, during the initialization of my view, I add a couple of image elements from code behind:

```
foreach (Carousel e in partner.getPartnerItem())
{
    dots.Children.Add(new Image
    {
        Source = "dot_unselected.png",
    });
}
```

Here `getPartnerItem` is a list of objects, that serve to determine how many `Images` the view should hold. In this context, "dots" is a `StackLayout`.

From my ViewModel, which is named `carouselViewModel` I dynamically select `Image` elements i.e.:

```
public bool isSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _isSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(isSelected)));
    }
}
```

The `_isSelected` is changed from another model, in which a timer triggers the event.

Naturally, since my images are added dynamically, I don't have the ability to do a standard binding like so:

```
<Image Source="{Binding whatEverProperty}"/>
```

Therefore, I tried to do the following in my code behind, like so:

```
public FrontPage()
{
    Image currentSlider;

    for (int i = 0; i <= partner.getPartnerItem().Count() ; i++)
    {
        if (carouselViewModel.numberInList == i && carouselViewModel.isSelected)
        {
            currentSlider = (Image)dots.Children.ElementAt(i);
            currentSlider.Source = "dot_selected.png";
        }
        else
        {
            currentSlider = (Image)dots.Children.ElementAt(i);
            currentSlider.Source = "dot_unselected.png";
        }
    }
}
```

Above, I try to associate the `Image` in the `StackLayout` named "dots" that corresponds to the object in the list through `getPartnerItem()`. Additionally, I fetch the `carouselViewModel.numberInList` which basically serves to tell which object is selected in the list.

Unfortunately, nothing happens and my Images persist having "dot_unselected.png" as their source.

To summarize, is there a way to bind my images to my ViewModel with unique identifiers, when i add my elements dynamically as i do in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a binding in code

```
myImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "BindingPath");
```

Comment: Thank you. Would it be viable, to put the above for-loop inside a threaded method? Or is it bad code practice?

Comment: I'm not sure what difference that would make

Comment: the problem is, that if i utilize the method from your answer. I would have the same binding on all three images. In this case, I want to be able to target the individual images, so that i can change the image of the element that corresponds to the item in the `partner.getPartnerItem()`.

Comment: you question is literally "Add binding to elements that are created in codebehind" and that's what I showed you how to do.   If you just want to manually set a property in code behind, that is NOT data binding.

Comment: Looking at [Binding Path doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.setbinding?view=xamarin-forms), I believe `"BindingPath"` should instead be `new Binding("MyProperty")`, or more generally `new Binding("MyProperty.MySubProperty...")`, where "MyProperty" is a Property within current BindingContext. (Can't just use the Path string directly, according to Intellisense - need a Binding object.)